How to check if a vector in 3D space is pointing towards the interior of a sphere?
If I have the velocity vector of a point in the 3D space specified as $\vec{v}=[x_v \ y_v \ z_v]^T$, how can I test if it points towards the interior of a 3-dimensional sphere $S$ with its center placed at $ C_S = (x_S,y_s,z_S)$ and of radius $r_S$?
To describe it simpler, how can I test whether the point will collide with the sphere or not ?
EDIT: The velocity vector of the point is not constant as time passes.

is $v$ a constant vector? in such case you also need a starting point

If $v$ starts at a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, then you just need to check if $(x_0+tx_v-x_S)^2+ (y_0+ty_v-y_S)^2+ (z_0+tz_v-z_S)^2 = r^2$ has nonnegative real solutions for $t$.

If you need to write code for this, look up "ray-sphere intersection". The "ray" is (your point + $t\vec v$) for some $t \in \mathbb R$.

@SBF No, the $v$ vector is not constant. My mistake that I did not mention it. Added as an edit.

@kieransquared This formula fits to the case when the velocity vector is constant as time passes.

In response to your edit: Are you interested in checking for collision assuming the point continues in the current direction (determined by the current velocity), or are you looking to see if the potentially curved path passes through the sphere?

@TeoProtoulis in the case when the velocity is non constant, replace $x_0 + tx_v$ with the x coordinate of the solution to the ODE $dr/dt = v$ with appropriate initial conditions, and same for the other coordinates.

@FilipMilovanović I am interested in checking for collision assuming the point continues in the current direction.

@TeoProtoulis - in that case, it doesn't matter that the velocity vector is not constant in time (it's only the direction that really matters, and the exact magnitude of $\vec v$ is irrelevant, except in that the value of the $t$ parameter depends on it). The approaches suggested that assume a constant $\vec v$ will work. Just to be on the same page, the $t$ here is not (necessarily) time, just a parameter that arbitrarily "slides" your point along the line extending the velocity vector in either direction (or scales the vector, if you like).

You need the starting point $P$ as well as the velocity $V$. Then the object moves along the line $P+tV$ as $t$ varies. Use the formula at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html for the distance from a point (the center of the sphere) to that line to see if it's less than the radius. If it is, then check that the close point is when $t>0$ so the nearest pass isn't in the past.
You might want to check first that the point isn't inside the sphere to begin with.
